Flutter Build Errors
I'm currently facing some issues while building my Flutter project for Android, and I'm stuck on a few errors. Here are the details:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_geocoder'.
Execution failed for task ':flutter_compass'.
Execution failed for task ':flutter_barcode_scanner'.

I’m using Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.1, on macOS 14.5 23F79 darwin-arm64, locale en-IN). I’ve tried some troubleshooting, but nothing seems to work.
Has anyone faced similar issues or have any suggestions on how to resolve them? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance for your guidance!
I tried my best, but it's not working.

Fewer emojis and more [mcve] please. What do you mean by "not working"? What happens when you run which code and and what were you expecting to happen instead? See also [ask].

I don't think this even shows the error related to the problem

Make sure you set the compileSdkVersion correctly in your build.gradle file.
compileSdkVersion 34


Nice to meet you.
If everything was working fine before, would you like to try what I'm suggesting?
Try it
remove pubspec.lock file. 
Also, try running the following command in the terminal.
flutter clean
flutter pub get

There are several commands you could try, like selecting stable or running pub cache clean,
but I resolved a similar issue using the method I mentioned above.
I really hope this helps fix the problem!
and I agree measure targetSdkVersion 34 too. 
UPDATE: try rebuild project
or invalidate caches clear files.
Thanks!
